# Getting error while checkout in git

Tags: git, git-clone

I am using the below command in terminal.

```
$ git checkout https://coding@bitbucket.org/coding/coding.git
```

but getting the below error

```
error: pathspec 'https:/coding@bitbucket.org/coding/coding.git' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Please help me to checkout the repository by git command. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `git clone` to clone a repository:

inside your working directory (normally NOT inside a git repository):

```
git clone https://coding@bitbucket.org/coding/coding.git
```

Comment: If I use "git clone" than can I commit and update from the working directory.

Comment: yes. git clone means you get a local copy of the whole git repository (including its history). You can then commit and so on

Comment: when i am using "git push" command its giving me the below error.

fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

    git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

    git push <name>

Comment: that's another question... consider following a small git tutorial. you need to add a remote in order to be able to push; something like "git remote add ..."

Comment: if your problem is solved, consider accepting the answer; so other users can see that this is solved...